# celery beat container gets stuck

Tags: docker, celery, celerybeat

I started running a celery beat worker in a dedicated container. This works fine sometimes, but now I get the following error trying to remove or re-deploy my containers:

```
An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
```

Also, I cannot access the container anymore and the following commands just get stuck:

```
docker restart beat
docker logs beat
docker exec beat bash
```